# Differential function from $(0,1]$ onto $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any differentiable function defined on $(0,1]$ whose range is $(0,1)$?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xdano.jpg) is what this sort of thing looks like.

Answer (score 4):

Consider 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1+\left(1-\frac x2\right)\,\sin\frac1x}2.
$$
If $x>\delta$, then $|f(x)|=f(x)\leq(1+(1-\delta/2))/2=1=\delta/4$. But near zero, the function approaches both 1 and 0. So its range is $(0,1)$.

Comment: This function has infinitely many zeroes: $1/2n \pi$ for $n \ge 1$, so in the range there is $0$ as well...

Comment: Good point, thanks. I removed the square so the function have $(-1,1)$ as range, and then scaled and translated.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( (1-x) \sin \left( \frac{1}{x}\right) + 1 \right)$$

Comment: Not defined at $1$, is it?

Comment: Sorry, I had in mind the domain $[0,1)$

Comment: Works as edited, I think.